# Youtube Data API V3 Number of results not equal to maxResults/pageInfo.resultsPerPage

Tags: youtube-api

Good day. I'm trying to get the top videos for gaming within the specified publish dates ordered by view count. I'm having a problem with the number of items that it is returning in the JSON response because it's less than 50 items even though I have set the maxResults parameter to 50 and the JSON response returns pageInfo.resultsPerPage equal to 50. The pageInfo.totalResults also returns a lot more than 50 so it should be displaying 50 items in the result. As an example, I'm using the followng URL

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={API_Key}&part=snippet&maxResults=50&order=viewCount&publishedAfter=2017-02-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&publishedBefore=2017-02-01T00%3A01%3A59Z&type=video&videoCategoryId=20

The returned result here the last time I ran this query has 20 items even though there are 161,307 total results. I would like to ask a solution that will make sure that I will always get the number of items equal to the maxResults if possible. Hope someone can help me on this. Thank you very much.

EDIT:  I know how to use the page token, but I'm not aiming for getting the items that I need for more than one request (as the Data API have limited credits per day). The issue that I'm trying to resolve is to make sure that I always get 50 items everytime I invoke the request.

Comment: You Can use Nextpage token for display more videos

Comment: `Values must be within the range: [0, 50]` You can use Nextpage Token For View more videos

Comment: The value that I'm using is 50 for the maxResults so it should be a valid value. Based on the documentation The maxResults parameter specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set. My assumption is that the result set is the result "after" my filter parameters have been applied. I know how to use the page token, but I'm not aiming for getting the items that I need for more than one request (as the Data API have limited credits per day). The issue that I'm trying to resolve is to make sure that I always get 50 items everytime I invoke the request.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are 160k+ total results, your publishedAfter/publishedBefore filters cut the number returned down to the videos published in that time range, which is 20.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have a reference for this? According to the documentation

pageInfo.totalResults is The total number of results in the result set.

I assume that by result set, it means the results after the filter has been applied. Also for what it's worth, there's a value in the nextPageToken field of the search result. If my publish date range cuts off the results to 20 as you're claiming, I think it doesn't make sense that they're giving a page token to view the next set of results.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got 50 results with the URL request that you provided. Just make sure that you place right value on the parameter that you use, especially the value in `publishedAfter`. You can also use the parameter [`pageToken`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageToken) to get the next page or next 50 results.

For more information, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132945/unable-to-get-the-second-page-of-search-using-page-tokens-youtube-api-search/42156606#42156606) on how to use `pageToken`

Comment: Thanks for your response. The number of items I get is actually inconsistent. I tried it now and it returned 18 items. I know how to use the page token, but I'm not aiming for getting the items that I need for more than one request (as the Data API have limited credits per day). The issue that I'm trying to resolve is to make sure that I always get 50 items everytime I invoke the request. Now I'm wondering if the API somehow has a timeout for fetching requests, and in my connection I always get that timeout before the 50 items are completed. Just an educated guess.